# Run Java httpd server as service on GNU/Linux

Tags: bash, java, systemd

I have Java app with built-in grizzly http server. And I can't run it, neither in foreground nor as service from systemd.

It is shutting itself down right after start. Am I missing something?

If I run from bash the shell remains opened - everythink is ok:

```
[root@Test-LAPP02 RL_acskidd] java -jar RestListener-3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar    
    Oct 24, 2017 5:00:37 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
        INFO: Started listener bound to [192.168.18.41:1177]
        Oct 24, 2017 5:00:37 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
        INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
        Oct 24, 2017 5:00:38 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
        INFO: Started listener bound to [192.168.18.41:1188]
        Oct 24, 2017 5:00:38 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
        INFO: [HttpServer-1] Started.
```

But if I try to start it as systemd service (or even in foreground with & at the end of command ) it goes down right after the start:

```
[root@Test-LAPP02 RL_acskidd]# systemctl start rl_acskidd
Oct 24 17:08:29 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: Oct 24, 2017 5:08:29 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
Oct 24 17:08:29 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: INFO: Started listener bound to [192.168.18.41:1177]
Oct 24 17:08:29 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: Oct 24, 2017 5:08:29 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
Oct 24 17:08:29 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: Oct 24, 2017 5:08:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: INFO: Started listener bound to [192.168.18.41:1188]
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: Oct 24, 2017 5:08:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: INFO: [HttpServer-1] Started.
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: Oct 24, 2017 5:08:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: INFO: Stopped listener bound to [192.168.18.41:1177]
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: Oct 24, 2017 5:08:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 Rest Listener ACSKIDD[1826]: INFO: Stopped listener bound to [192.168.18.41:1188]
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 1826 (java).
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 systemd[1]: Child 1826 (java) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 systemd[1]: Child 1826 belongs to rl_acskidd.service
Oct 24 17:08:31 Test-LAPP02 systemd[1]: rl_acskidd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
```

Here is my unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rest Listener
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=service
User=nobody
SyslogIdentifier=Rest Listener
WorkingDirectory=/opt/RL_acskidd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar RestListener-3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I googled about that problem and I saw that Java app should be written with 'run as service' functionality, but I also see that many people still can do tricks with running it as systemd unit.

I tried various of ExecStart= options to simulate shell, like this one:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/java -jar RestListener-3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
```

But still no luck. Where should look to solve this? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is found by running `systemd-analyze verify` on you file, revealing this error:

`systemd-analyze verify ./foo.service 
[/home/mark/tmp/foo.service:6] Failed to parse service type, ignoring: service`

Please review `man systemd.service` and select the correct `Type=` value for your service.

Be sure to check `journalctl` and `journalctl -u your-service-name` for errors after attempting to start your service.

Comment: I want specify service type because 'simple' is default type. In my post all output selected from journactl .

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark here, but is it possible that the `nobody` user is not able to access some files or cannot open a listening port? I see that when trying your program in `bash` You used the `root` user but in your `systemd` unit file You use `nobody`.